# Java/Android: Backslashes in JSON in Double Quotation places

Tags: json, backslash

I try to send "POST" request to serwer. Request includes JSON. Server returns "ok" or my JSON (in value of "message" key), if data in not correct. And I get strange backslashes ( \ sing) in my JSON, sent to server.
 I get JSON response:

```
{"message":{"{\"phone_number\":\"_380661111111\",\"password\":\"112233aa\",\"military_id\":\"12345\",\"email\":\"won@mail_ru\"}":""}}
```

Normal JSON:

```
{"phone_number":"380666320670","password":"112233aa","military_id":"12345","email":"wovilon@mail.ru"}
```

Full code:

```
class SendLoginData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
String[] key,value;
String mResultString;

SendLoginData(String[] inKey, String[] inValue ){
    this.key=new String[inKey.length];
    this.value=new String[inValue.length];
    this.key=inKey;
    this.value=inValue;
}
String resultString = null;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {//    http://oasushqg.beget.tech/users
        String myURL = "http://y937220i.bget.ru/users";
        byte[] data = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            //Create JSONObject here
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            for (int i=0; i<this.key.length; i++) {
                jsonParam.put(this.key[i], this.value[i]);

            }
            data=jsonParam.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            os.write(data);
            Log.d("MyLOG", "data is next: "+new String(data, "UTF-8"));
            data = null;

            conn.connect();
            int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                is = conn.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // Такого вот размера буфер
                // Далее, например, вот так читаем ответ
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                data = baos.toByteArray();
                resultString = new String(data, "UTF-8");

                JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(resultString);
                mResultString=jsonObj.getString("message");

            } else {
                }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(resultString != null) {
        Log.d("MyLOG", "postExecute run");
        Log.d("MyLOG", mResultString);

    }

}}
```

Comment: The problem was resolved by setting requestCode property: conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

Comment: Did you solved this issue just add the `setRequestProperty`? I have the same issue, and I have already set this. My Json string it's ok (Without backslashes) but when the request was made, the server on the other side receive the json string with backslashes.

Comment: See another lines in your class, do they coorelate with my code? If yes, you may try to use free json test servers, like http://www.jsontest.com